# sticky of navbar is effecting other divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a navbar and used sticky to fix the navbar at the top of the webpage. The problem is, when sticky is being activated, it is push the image below it a bit. How do I prevent this from happening? I thought the problem was because of differences in how I used position property but I have a similar code that is working with no problems. Also, will help if anyone can share how to make the sticky transition smooth and seamless. I am attaching part of code for the same

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  myFunction()
};

var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky")
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
```

```css
.main-navbar {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 17px;
  left: 20%;
  top: 0px;
}


/*Code for Sticky*/

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 99999999;
  transition: 0.3s top ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s top ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: 0.3s top ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
  animation: faceInEffect 0.3s;
  -webkit-animation: faceInEffect 0.3s;
  box-shadow: -1px 2px 4px rgb(110, 109, 109);
}

@keyframes faceInEffect {
  from {
    top: 0px;
  }
  to {
    top: 10px;
  }
}

.hero>img {
  position: relative;
  top: 6.7rem;
  left: 4.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-navbar" id="navbar">
  <nav>
    <ul class="nav-list">
      <li class="dropdown-item-1">
        <a href="">Men</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a href="#">shirts</a> </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>



<div class="contentforscroll>

 src=" https://static.nike.com/a/images/f_auto/dpr_1.0,cs_srgb/w_906,c_limit/83f15213-514a-4963-a765-74c379b89a34/nike-just-do-it.png "
        alt=" " style="width: 1300px; ">
<img  src="https://static.nike.com/a/images/f_auto/dpr_1.0,cs_srgb/w_906,c_limit/83f15213-514a-4963-a765-74c379b89a34/nike-just-do-it.png "
        alt=" " style="width: 1300px; ">></img>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you use css `position:sticky;`?

Comment: I've tried it but doesn't seem to work in my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this problem because - your nav section is out of Normal Flow when sticky. You need to wrap your `<div class="main-navbar" id="navbar">` div with height = height .main-navbar.

```
<div class="wrapp-main-navbar">
   <div class="main-navbar" id="navbar">...</div>
</div>
```

css

```
.wrapp-main-navbar {
  height: 85px;
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help. However, can you kindly let me know how you figured out the problem or guide me to resources so I can learn myself?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `position:sticky;`

And it's not necessary to use css animation.

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  myFunction()
};

var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  navbar.classList.toggle("shadow", window.pageYOffset > sticky);
}
```

```css
.main-navbar {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
  position: sticky;
  padding-bottom: 17px;
  left: 20%;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 99999999;
  top: 0px;
  transition: top 0.3s;
}


/*Code for Sticky*/

.shadow {
  top: 10px;
  box-shadow: -1px 2px 4px rgb(110, 109, 109);
}

.hero>img {
  position: relative;
  top: 6.7rem;
  left: 4.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-navbar" id="navbar">
  <nav>
    <ul class="nav-list">
      <li class="dropdown-item-1">
        <a href="">Men</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a href="#">shirts</a> </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
<div class="contentforscroll"><img src=" https://static.nike.com/a/images/f_auto/dpr_1.0,cs_srgb/w_906,c_limit/83f15213-514a-4963-a765-74c379b89a34/nike-just-do-it.png " alt=" " style=" width: 1300px; " /></div>
```

Comment: hey, thanks for taking the time to share this. However, this doesn't seem to work in my code. Maybe because there is a clash between properties. My code is big so Im reluctant to figure out the problem. Thanks for the help though